# join using data.table in r

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have some data like this:

```
library(data.table)
# example daycare
rewards <- data.table(ChildNumber = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), 
                      StartDate = as.Date(c("2015-1-1", "2015-2-1", "2015-3-1", "2015-4-1", "2015-5-1", "2015-6-1")), 
                      EndDate = as.Date(c("2015-2-1", "2015-3-1", "2015-4-1", NA, NA, NA)), 
                      Treat = c("pop", "cookie", "star", "pop", "cookie", "star")
                      )
awards <- data.table(ChildNumber = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                     StartDate = as.Date(c("2015-1-1", "2015-1-8", "2015-1-15",  
                                           "2015-2-1", "2015-2-8", "2015-2-15", 
                                           "2015-3-1", "2015-3-8", "2015-3-15",  
                                           "2015-4-1", "2015-4-8", "2015-4-15" )), 
                     EndDate = as.Date(c("2015-1-7", "2015-1-14", "2015-1-21", 
                                          "2015-2-7", "2015-2-14", "2015-2-15",  
                                          "2015-3-7", "2015-3-14", "2015-3-15", 
                                          "2015-4-7", "2015-4-14", "2015-4-15" ))
                    )
```

I need to add a Treat column to the awards data.table based on the date range specified in the rewards table.

I tried this:

```
merged <- rewards[awards, on=list(ChildNumber, StartDate >= StartDate, EndDate <= EndDate)]
```

but got NAs in the Treat column.   I know the data is not tidy, I guess it needs an ID field. I suppose this is really a non-equi join? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, it's a nonequi join. Your condition says: the rewards period must be entirely contained within the awards period for a match. The syntax is `x[i, on=.(xcol >= icol, xcol2 <= icol2, ...)]`.

Comment: ok, got my x and i mixed up, thanks. Any ideas on dealing with NAs in a join? I tried this: `merged <- rewards[awards, on=list(ChildNumber, StartDate >= StartDate, EndDate <= EndDate | is.na(EndDate))]` but get error. I want it to return the Treat if the date is between StartDate and (NA) EndDate.

Comment: For Dates, if you want to treat NA as -Inf or +Inf, you can do that: `DT = data.table(id = 1:2, d = as.Date(Sys.Date()) + 0:1); DT[2, d := -Inf][d < Sys.Date()]` It prints as NA but for inequalities, it works as expected. This loophole may be a bug, though.

Comment: that worked fine Frank, thanks. `rewards[is.na(EndDate), EndDate := Inf]`